# SSIS Script component runtime error: "invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xff" while bulk copy to Posgtres db

Tags: postgresql, ssis, blob, bulkinsert, npgsql

i'm trying to fast load BLOB data into postgresql database via SSIS using Script Component with code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
using Npgsql;
using NpgsqlTypes;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    NpgsqlConnection sqlConn;
    NpgsqlBinaryImporter writer;

    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();

        sqlConn = (NpgsqlConnection)this.Connections.Connection.AcquireConnection(null);                       
        writer = sqlConn.BeginBinaryImport (
            @"COPY ""tempdownload"".""MyTable""(
                ""id"",
                ""Description""
                )
            FROM STDIN (FORMAT BINARY)"
        );
    }

    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        writer.StartRow();
        if (!Row.cid_IsNull) writer.Write(Row.cid, NpgsqlDbType.Integer); else writer.WriteNull();
        if (!Row.cDescription_IsNull) writer.Write(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Row.cDescription.GetBlobData(0, Convert.ToInt32(Row.cDescription.Length))), NpgsqlDbType.Text); else writer.WriteNull();        
    }

    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();

        writer.Close();
        sqlConn.Close();

        this.ReleaseConnections();
    }
}
```

sometimes i catch an error
[image]

the error does not appear at particular row but it does at particular row set

i tried to use

```
writer.Write(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Row.cDescription.GetBlobData(0, Convert.ToInt32(Row.cDescription.Length))).TrimEnd(new char[] { (char)13 }), NpgsqlDbType.Text);
```

and

```
writer.Write(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Row.cDescription.GetBlobData(0, Convert.ToInt32(Row.cDescription.Length))).Replace((char)13, (char)10), NpgsqlDbType.Text);
```

it works well

but unfortunately these solutions involves changes of data

is it possible to write data without any changes?

Comment: I guess its necessary change as you are moving data from one type to other.

Comment: original type is postgresql text. so it should be put into postgresql text through blob

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
//...
if (!Row.cDescription_IsNull) writer.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Row.cDescription.GetBlobData(0, Convert.ToInt32(Row.cDescription.Length)))), NpgsqlDbType.Text); else writer.WriteNull();
//...
```

then

```
insert into public."MyTable"(
    "id",
    "Description"
    )
select
    "id",
    "Description"::json#>>'{}'
from "tempdownload"."MyTable"
--...
```